# How do I use/include StrContains in NSIS

Tags: nsis

Do I need to include a specific .nsh library or function definition to use the function 'StrContains' in NSIS?

I have looked for a download for the library but I cant seem to find it?

When I go to compile this code I get the compile error: *"Invalid command: ${StrContains}"*

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"

# Compile error below
!macro test
   ${StrContains} $0 $1 "abc"
!macroend

Section 
  DetailPrint ""
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the function definition shown in the [StrContains function page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrContains) of the NSIS wiki (in the category of [strings functions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aString_Functions)) in your code.

Don't forget the last statement `!define StrContains ...` to be able to call it with `${StrContains}`